# Bind ddl in gridview that is already bound

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am trying to have the ddl bound when the search box returns a result. The DDL is bound as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Area" SortExpression="ServiceArea">
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_Val_ServiceArea" runat="server" DataTextField="ServiceArea"
        DataValueField='<%# Eval("ServiceAreaId") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Bind_ServiceArea" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceArea") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The page loads fine when I use the search and the grid loads.
When I press the edit button the exception is Object not set to an instance.
And errors on `ddl.DataTextField = "ServiceArea"`.

```
protected void grd_User_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
grd_User.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;


using (var _db = new dbDataContext())
{
    var result = from s in _db.tbl_ServiceAreas
                    where s.Deleted == false
                    select new
                    {
                        s.ServiceAreaId,
                        s.ServiceArea
                    };

    if ((DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)grd_User.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("drp_Val_ServiceArea");

        ddl.DataTextField = "ServiceArea";
        ddl.DataValueField = "ServiceAreaId";
        ddl.DataSource = result;
        ddl.DataBind();

    }
}
 LoadGrid();
}
```

Is this because the grid is already bound to the ServiceArea?

Below is the Answer I have been looking for.

```
        protected void grd_User_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("drp_Val_ServiceArea");

            using (var _db = new dbDataContext())
            {
                var result = from s in _db.tbl_Users
                             where s.Deleted == false
                             select new
                             {
                                 s.ServiceAreaId,
                                 s.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea
                             };

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    ddl.DataTextField = item.ServiceArea;
                    ddl.DataValueField = item.ServiceAreaId.ToString();
                    ddl.DataSource = result;
                    ddl.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. This is because it find find your `ddl` control. Inspect your Controls collection and verify that `drp_Val_ServiceArea` is present

Comment: What do you mean? I can see the ID in the first bit of the code shown. Is that not good enough?

Comment: No, that is not enough. A gridview can add extra columns for buttons like select or edit. Assuming that your control is in `Cell[0]` may be wrong. Debug is your friend.

Comment: ok.. do the columns start at the left @ 0 and move along to the right as you see them displayed or do you count all your Templatefield's ?

Comment: They start at the left and move along.

Comment: I have removed the `Cell[0]` and still get the same result. Can I check through debugging that it has found the `drp_Val_ServiceArea`

Comment: Take a look at the `Controls` Collection of `Cell[0]`

Comment: What was the issue? I would like to put it down as an answer and close the question

Comment: It just wont get the `            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)grd_User.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("drp_Val_ServiceArea");
` But I have learnt that you cannot directly access controls at RowEditing. I need Pre-Render.